# Recommended NUMA nodes per socket on dual AMD Epyc 7643 server with 1TB of RAM

Tags: numa

What do you suggest to set the NUMA nodes per socket to? It is factory set to NPS1, but I'm not sure if this is the most optimal value. (We use this device for massively multithreaded bioinformatic tasks)

The possible choice is: NPS0 (will attempt to interleave the 2 sockets together) NPS1, NPS2, NP3, NPS4, Auto (OS: Ubuntu 21.10, 5.13.0-40-generic kernel, 8x128 Gb of RAM)

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> What do you suggest to set the NUMA nodes per socket to?

The number of actual NUMA nodes on your system - it should be set to that and nothing else. You don't mention your system layout or any other details, let us know and we might be able to help.

Comment: Finally I set it to AUTO, and listed the nodes (attached to the original post). I hope it is brings us closer to the solution.  Also NUMA balancing is turned on with sudo -u root sysctl -w kernel.numa_balancing=1

Thanks!

Comment: But what is your server and CPU/s?

Comment: OH sorry, I've just lost in benchmarking: GIGABYTE MZ72-HB0 board with 2X AMD Epyc 7643 CPUs. 
Meanwhile upgraded to Kernel 5.18RC1, unfortunately without any performance increase.

Comment: More details about benchmarking: https://github.com/bbuchfink/diamond/issues/555

Comment: This is of interest - https://documentation.suse.com/sbp/all/single-html/SBP-AMD-EPYC-3-SLES15SP2/index.html#sec-epyc-architecture